# Set custom segue with SW Reveal Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I have used SW reveal controller in my app. Here I used Two modules. one is registration and another one is Home module. I have connected the root view controller to login module with the segue name of "sw_front". And also My root view controller is connected to Home module through side bar table view controller with the segue name of "sw_rear".

Here my question is Registration module has worked properly, but after my registration I have to show directly the home module. once app will quit then user will come back to the app. How to make a function for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try not to set your SWReveal ViewController as initial ViewController.
You can make standalone Authorization ViewController and make it initial ViewController.
In this AuthorizationViewController you can instantiate SWRevealViewController after successful authorization, like this:

```
SWRevealViewController *revealVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SWRevealViewController"];

[self presentViewController:revealVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In your reveal view controller set sw_front - HomeViewController, and sw_rear - some MenuViewController, where you can add registration stuff.